# Kendo Grid Export to CSV File?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Still I did not find the exact way to Export Kendo Grid to CSV File. Please give a way to me.

Thanks InAdvance...!

Comment: Out of the box you only get Excel and PDF export.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/grid/csv-export-server-side) is CSV Export example project on GitHub.